# Understanding an approximation equation

Tags: approximation

In [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0878933085) biology textbook I found the following approximation:

$$\frac{1}{2N}\left(  1-\frac{1}{2N} \right)^t ≈ \frac{1}{2N}e^{\frac{-t}{2N}}$$

Can you help me to understand this approximation and help me to understand what assumption are needed for this approximation to be useful.

Comment: Have you heard of the Taylor/McLaurin series of logarithm in 0 ?

Comment: @T_O I know what is a Taylor series expansion. I don't know about McLauring series but from your comment I'd guess they are two names for the same series. I understand what is a taylor series of `log(x)` but I don't understand what we mean by "…of logarithm in o". Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I worded that poorly I will try to give a detailed answer

Comment: Ok others have given good enough answers. The key point is that you can replace a function by its first k terms in the Taylor/McLaurin (I don't know how it is called in English) as they are equivalent : their ratio will be 1, they behave the same way. Edit : for more information, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to define $e^x$ is via $$
  e^x = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n
$$

By re-arranging your forumula a bit, you get
$$
  \frac{1}{2N}\left(1 - \frac{1}{2N}\right)^t =  \frac{1}{2N}\underbrace{\left(1 + \frac{\frac{-t}{2N}}{t}\right)^t}_{\text{Compare to $e^x$ for $x=\frac{-t}{2N}$}}
  \approx  \frac{1}{2N}e^{-\frac{-t}{2N}} \text{,}
$$
at least for large enough $t$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you answer made things clear up to the understanding that $e^x = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n$. So [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754673/definition-of-the-constant-e) is my following question ;)

Answer (score 1):

Let us compare Taylor expansions of $\left(  1-\frac{1}{x} \right)^t$ and  $e^{\frac{-t}{x}}$ around $t=0$. For the first one, we have $$\left(  1-\frac{1}{x} \right)^t \simeq 1+t \log \left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} t^2 \log
   ^2\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{6} t^3 \log
   ^3\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)+O\left(t^4\right)$$ while for the second one, we have $$e^{\frac{-t}{x}}\simeq 1-\frac{t}{x}+\frac{t^2}{2 x^2}-\frac{t^3}{6 x^3}+O\left(t^4\right)$$ Now, in the first one, assume that $x$ is large compared to $1$ and use the Taylor expansion of $\log(1+y)$ for small values of $y$. Replace $y$ by $1/x$.

I am sure that you can take from here and conclude about the validity of the approximation.